Need assistance with Xpath expression to count non-null values after a delimiter
I have tried to make the following expression work in a power automate flow without luck. The objective of this expression is to count all the non-null values after the second ";" for each substring before "|" , AND each substring between "|" and the first ";" such as "2024-09" from the data sample.
xpath(
    outputs('Compose_3'),
    concat(
        'count(//root/item[starts-with(., "', 
        first(split(item(), '|')), 
        '") and normalize-space(substring-after(substring-after(., ";"), ";")) != "" and contains(., ";', 
        substring-before(substring-after(item(), "|"), ";"), 
        '")])'
    )
)

Here is a sample input for this xpath:
"Data and Analytics|2024-09;2024-09-30;",
"Data and Analytics|2024-09;2024-09-30;",
"Enterprise App and Emerging Tech|2024-09;2024-10-01;",
"Enterprise App and Emerging Tech|2024-09;2024-10-01;",
"Mobility and Customer Experience|2024-09;2024-10-07;2024-12-31",
"Mobility and Customer Experience|2024-09;2024-10-07;2024-12-31",
"Mobility and Customer Experience|2024-10;2024-10-27;2024-11-07",
"Data and Analytics|2024-10;2024-10-23;2024-12-08",
"Data and Analytics|2024-10;2024-10-23;2024-12-08",
"Cloud - Infra - CS and Obser|2024-10;2024-10-24;2024-12-15"


EDIT by @Fravadona
XML data, based on the comment and the question:
<root>
  <item>Data and Analytics|2024-09;2024-09-30;</item>
  <item>Data and Analytics|2024-09;2024-09-30;</item>
  <item>Enterprise App and Emerging Tech|2024-09;2024-10-01;</item>
  <item>Enterprise App and Emerging Tech|2024-09;2024-10-01;</item>
  <item>Mobility and Customer Experience|2024-09;2024-10-07;2024-12-31</item>
  <item>Mobility and Customer Experience|2024-09;2024-10-07;2024-12-31</item>
  <item>Mobility and Customer Experience|2024-10;2024-10-27;2024-11-07</item>
  <item>Data and Analytics|2024-10;2024-10-23;2024-12-08</item>
  <item>Data and Analytics|2024-10;2024-10-23;2024-12-08</item>
  <item>Cloud - Infra - CS and Obser|2024-10;2024-10-24;2024-12-15</item>
</root>

Here are the desired results based on the data above:


Your question is very unclear. Your sample input contains no XML, certainly not any root or item elements which your XPath is expecting. You're mixing XPath and power-automate expressions in a very confusing way.

Sorry for the confusion. Here is a sample XML output for the xpath:  "Enterprise App and Emerging Tech|2024-07;2024-07-30;Enterprise App and Emerging Tech|2024-07;2024-08-08;Enterprise App and Emerging Tech|2024-07;2024-07-30;Cloud - Infra - CS and Obser|2024-09;2024-09-30;2024-10-03

Based on the updates you've provided, I've rewritten my answer.
Grouping the data is not possible in XPath alone.  The following will do it for you though and do it easily.

Compose Data
This is your data as an array.  I'm making the assumption that you have that somewhere in your flow.
[
  "Data and Analytics|2024-09;2024-09-30;",
  "Data and Analytics|2024-09;2024-09-30;",
  "Enterprise App and Emerging Tech|2024-09;2024-10-01;",
  "Enterprise App and Emerging Tech|2024-09;2024-10-01;",
  "Mobility and Customer Experience|2024-09;2024-10-07;2024-12-31",
  "Mobility and Customer Experience|2024-09;2024-10-07;2024-12-31",
  "Mobility and Customer Experience|2024-10;2024-10-27;2024-11-07",
  "Data and Analytics|2024-10;2024-10-23;2024-12-08",
  "Data and Analytics|2024-10;2024-10-23;2024-12-08",
  "Cloud - Infra - CS and Obser|2024-10;2024-10-24;2024-12-15"
]

Select Enhanced Data
This step prepares the data for the next action.  It essentially breaks out the string into a more workable form.  This is the definition of the Select ...

{
  "type": "Select",
  "inputs": {
    "from": "@outputs('Compose_Data')",
    "select": {
      "Portfolio": "@first(split(item(), '|'))",
      "Period": "@first(split(last(split(item(), '|')), ';'))",
      "Count": "@if(endsWith(item(), ';'), 0, 1)"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "Compose_Data": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  }
}

The above produces this result ...
[
  {
    "Portfolio": "Data and Analytics",
    "Period": "2024-09",
    "Count": 0
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Data and Analytics",
    "Period": "2024-09",
    "Count": 0
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Enterprise App and Emerging Tech",
    "Period": "2024-09",
    "Count": 0
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Enterprise App and Emerging Tech",
    "Period": "2024-09",
    "Count": 0
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Mobility and Customer Experience",
    "Period": "2024-09",
    "Count": 1
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Mobility and Customer Experience",
    "Period": "2024-09",
    "Count": 1
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Mobility and Customer Experience",
    "Period": "2024-10",
    "Count": 1
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Data and Analytics",
    "Period": "2024-10",
    "Count": 1
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Data and Analytics",
    "Period": "2024-10",
    "Count": 1
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Cloud - Infra - CS and Obser",
    "Period": "2024-10",
    "Count": 1
  }
]

Aggregate
Now you need to use this handy little operation from the Advanced Data Operations connector.  It performs a GROUP BY on the data you give it using the aggregation operation of your choice.
You can see how that step is defined in the original image above.
That will produce this result which is in line with your expectations ...
[
  {
    "Portfolio": "Cloud - Infra - CS and Obser",
    "Period": "2024-10",
    "Count": 1
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Data and Analytics",
    "Period": "2024-09",
    "Count": 0
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Data and Analytics",
    "Period": "2024-10",
    "Count": 2
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Enterprise App and Emerging Tech",
    "Period": "2024-09",
    "Count": 0
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Mobility and Customer Experience",
    "Period": "2024-09",
    "Count": 2
  },
  {
    "Portfolio": "Mobility and Customer Experience",
    "Period": "2024-10",
    "Count": 1
  }
]

https://statesolutions.com.au/aggregate/
https://statesolutions.com.au/pricing/
If you don't want to use that, you'll need to loop and do the hard work that comes with that approach.

That would get the total for non-null values, and it will be identical for all records. But my objective is not this. The objective is getting this total for (for each substring before "|") , AND (each substring between "|" and the first ";").

@Ashraf Add the expected result to the sample data in your question so that people can understand better what you really want.

@Fravadona I have just done that

Right, ok, I get it now.

@Ashraf As Skin stated in his answer, grouping data isn't possible with XPath 1.0 directly

is it neccessary to stick with xml and xpath? What if you make an array from your input, then find the starting and the ending position of your string, then make an array of your result strings?
(for example: "Data and Analytics|2024-09;2024-09-30;": you need the substring between 19th and 27th characters, and your result would be "2024-09" ).

where:

'Apply to each':
variables('varArray')

'Compose - Start':
add(indexOf(item(),'|'),1)

'Compose - Length':
substring(item(),outputs('Compose_-Start'),outputs('Compose-_Length'))

Append to array variable:
outputs('Compose')



Thanks for your input. I know there are alternatives. But xpath is much faster for 100's or 1000's of records. Xpath is still like a mystery to me but it is worth all the time and effort to learn.
